# Issue in Query Formation

Tags: sql, case

I am facing issue in query formation, require your inputs. Scenario is as below:

I am having three color of t-shirts that is blue, yellow and red. Each student is bind with one color t-shirt only. Can you help me to find out number of t-shirt of each color in a class(2/3/4) means group by class 2/3/4.

In DB we have studentId, class and stShirtColor(B/Y/R)

Thanks in advance

Comment: OK its easy. Show us what you have now and we will try to correct it?

Comment: I know that CASE will be used here but haven't made anything as I don't know how to use increment in sql

Comment: ok there would be many similar questions on SO, try to search and customize it if needed. If still you dont get it, post it here.

Answer (score 0):

You can get and print the color of the Tshirt and its count for each class by following query,

```
SELECT class, stShirtColor, count(*) as NUMBER_OF_TSHIRST FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE class IN (2,3,4) group by class, stShirtColor;
```

Group By will organize your data based on class. You can use most [aggregate functions](http://databases.about.com/od/sql/l/aaaggregate1.htm) when using GROUP BY.

Comment: This can work in MySQL but not in ms sql server or oracle. Also it should be `group by class, stShirtColor` as OP wants `number of t-shirt of each color in a class(2/3/4)`

Comment: Every DBMS except MySQL will reject this statement.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are looking for :

```
SELECT class,
       stShirtColor,
       Count(*) AS NumberOfTshirts
FROM   yourtable
WHERE  class IN( 2, 3, 4 )
GROUP  BY class,stShirtColor
```

`where` clause will filter out the results as what you need and `group by` will make group of `class,stShirtColor` combination and ultimately count(*) will give you count of such groups.